# rearrange the characters of a string so that any two adjacent characters are not the same

Tags: c#, arrays, string, char

How to rearrange the characters of a string so that any two adjacent characters are not the same? using c#
c#
Without using Hashmaps and Dictionary
I managed to find each element of the string, and the occurrence of each element.
[This](https://onlinegdb.com/zfnUVjOp6) is what I've done so far

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ, you can gather the characters of the `string`, group them by duplicate characters, then pivot the groups and join then back into a `string`.

First, some extension methods to make `Join` easier:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<char> chars) => String.Concat(chars); // faster >= .Net Core 2.1
    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> strings) => String.Concat(strings);
}
```

Then, an extension method to pivot an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`:

```
public static class IEnumerableIEnumerableExt {
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Pivot<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> src) {
        var enums = src.Select(ie => ie.GetEnumerator()).ToList();
        var hasMores = Enumerable.Range(0, enums.Count).Select(n => true).ToList();

        for (; ; ) {
            var oneGroup = new List<T>();
            var hasMore = false;
            for (int j1 = 0; j1 < enums.Count; ++j1) {
                if (hasMores[j1]) {
                    hasMores[j1] = enums[j1].MoveNext();
                    hasMore = hasMore || hasMores[j1];
                    if (hasMores[j1])
                        oneGroup.Add(enums[j1].Current);
                }
            }

            if (!hasMore)
                break;

            yield return oneGroup;
        }

        for (int j1 = 0; j1 < enums.Count; ++j1)
            enums[j1].Dispose();
    }
}
```

Finally, use these to solve your problem:

```
var s = "How to rearrange the characters of a string";

var tryAns = s.OrderBy(c => c)
              .GroupBy(ch => ch)
              .Pivot()
              .Select(gch => gch.Join())
              .Join();

var dupRE = new Regex(@"(.)\1", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var hasDups = dupRE.IsMatch(tryAns);

// tryAns will be " Hacefghinorstw aceghnorst aeort aert ar r "
// hasDups will be false
```

If the resulting string has two adjacent identical characters, then `hasDups` will be true.